# Why does Autolayout not produce consistent results?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, autolayout

Either I'm out of my mind, or **AutoLayout** is straight broken. Can someone please explain this to me. I have a `TableViewCell` in a `TableView` that spans the width of the ViewController.  I put 4 Labels inside my `TableViewCell`.  I created constraints using AutoLayout such that each label is 25% the width of the `TableViewCell`.  And yet, the 4 labels are CLEARLY different widths and they don't even add up to 100% of the width of the entire cell.  Here's the screenshot.  (Horizontal position of each of the labels is ambiguous, yes, but that shouldn't make a difference).  Why are they not the same width?  And why does 25% + 25% + 25% + 25% not add up to 100%?  Running XCode 7.2 and targeting iOS 9.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are your width constraints required (have priority 1000?

Comment: Remove all constraints.Try these constraints select all 4 views at once than give top,leading,trailing and than equal widths constraint.

Comment: "Horizontal position of each of the labels is ambiguous, yes, but that shouldn't make a difference" - No, it does make a difference.  This is Autolayout telling you that it is going to have to make some guesses to layout your items.  Those guesses aren't the guesses you wanted.

Comment: @Paulw11 surely the guess it's making is simply the horizontal position of the view, right?  I don't see how having an ambiguous horizontal position should affect the width of the view...AutoLayout should be able to guess at the horizontal layout without altering the width, which is clearly specified right?  Otherwise what this means is "if you leave any 1 constraint unspecified, AutoLayout will throw all the other constraints out the window" - can that really be how it works?

Comment: No, if it can't solve the horizontal position then it may not be able to solve the horizontal width either.  Generally if you get those warnings in IB then things aren't going to go well.

Comment: Wow, well ok then.  That's pretty much what Daniel's answer said as well, just seems wild that 1 ambiguous constraint can ruin the others.  Thanks for filling me in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Error Symbol]

This red error symbol is Interface Builder telling you that it cannot solve your constraints.  In this case, as you have said, it's likely because you have not provided x position constraints for the labels.

Auto layout can either solve all constraints and get a right layout, or it can't and the result will be undefined. Remember that auto layout is an algebra-based process that solves for unknown values by using known values that you provide in constraints. If you don't provide sufficient and unambiguous known values, the equations for the remaining values simply cannot be solved and there can be no expectation of a correct result. The solution is to create enough constraints to make the layout solvable.

As a note, as of iOS 9 I would suggest using a UIStackView to hold those labels.  UIStackView exists precisely to take the pain out of setting up manual constraints for these types of scenarios.  If you used a horizontal stack view in the cell, you would constrain its edges to the cell's edges, drag the 4 labels into it and set it to "Fill Equally".  And that's all you would need!

Comment: Dan, thanks for the answer.  Agreed, I could make this work with a stack view.  I'm just baffled why not specifying a horizontal position should affect the width of the view.  Your explanation that it's all based on a bunch of formulas makes some sense, it just seems crazy that if you leave 1 constraint ambiguous, AutoLayout will then ruin and get wrong all of the remaining constraints which weren't ambiguous.  If that's true though, then I suppose this is the correct answer ha

Comment: @A.Vin  It makes a little more sense when you consider that a width constraint doesn't necessarily get used to set a "width" in the final calculation.  Ultimately, auto layout is calculating a _frame_, and the width constraint provides a rule of where the right or left edge of the _frame_ is relative to the opposite edge.  But if the opposite edge is undefined (no x position constraint), you don't end up with a matching final width, you end up with a frame that is more like left: ??, top: 0, right: ?? + some width, bottom: 50.  And what exact coordinates are ?? + some width?

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Hall's answer has useful information, but doesn't tell you specifically why you're seeing what you're seeing, so I will.

Xcode doesn't always enforce your constraints in the storyboard editor until you ask it to. In this case, you can select the table view cell's content view and from the menu bar choose Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > All Views in BBRowTableViewCell > Update Frames. (Sometimes it takes two or three tries for Xcode to get everything right.)

However, you probably won't like the result. Because you haven't constrained the horizontal positions of the labels, Xcode will probably pile them all up at the left edge of the cell, or maybe somewhere outside the bounds of the cell where you can't even see them.

If your deployment target is iOS 9 or later, the easiest solution (as Daniel Hall said) is to put the labels in a `UIStackView` set to “Fill Equally”, and constrain the stack view's edges to the cell content view's edges.

If your deployment target is earlier than iOS 9, then you should create the constraints described by user3802077.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the answer - I already told XCode to auto-resolve the layout issues though - the only issue that remains unresolved according to my warnings is the ambiguous horizontal position.  It sounds like (based on Daniel's answer) that the answer is basically "if you leave any one constraint ambiguous, autolayout might implode and even get your specified constraints wrong."  Is that really correct?  I don't have enough ios experience to know.  Just seems kind of crazy that 1 ambiguous thing can throw of all the correctly specified constraints. Thanks for input, will be using stackview

Answer (score 0):

This is not the only way, but here is how I usually do it.

As you did for the top and bottom for each labels, then:

- Leading of label1 to leading of superview
- Trailing of label4 to trailing of superview

Then a constraint for each neighbouring label:

- label1.trailing to label2.leading,
- ...

Then put an equal width constraint from each labels to label1:

- label2 to label1
- label3 to label1
- label4 to label1

This should be it. No need of specifying 25%.

Comment: Thanks, this works correctly.  But my question wasn't really "how do I make this work" but rather "why is the way I currently have it no working", if that makes sense.  thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

For autolayout constraints it requires to give for constraint to particular object 
x,y position and hight , width 
If you are not giving any one of this it shows error to you.
So make sure to give all the require constraints to your object.

Other option is uistackview for the ios 9 and later. 
Here is a link for you to learn about stackview
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XqVWyA5PLwk